# SSIS Expressions - I need something like a Switch Statement

Tags: ssis

I have a data flow with a derived column. I want to convert the contents of a column using an expression as follows:

```
If the source value is 101 convert it to 1001
If the source value is 102 convert it to 2002
If the source value is 202 convert it to 2019
Etc.
```

It seems like a Switch/Case statement would be ideal here. Do SSIS expressions support a Switch/Case? If not, what is the best way to handle something like this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nested conditionals like this (but it gets cumbersome quickly)
(sourcecolumn == 101)?1001:(sourcecolumn == 102)?2002:(sourcecolumn == 202)?2019:sourcecolumn

This translates roughly to nested if statements

if source value = 101 then 1001
else if source value = 102 then 2002
else if source value = 202 then 2019
else source value